# Post to my timeline in Facebook

Tags: facebook, sdk, posts

Please suggest how to post some text which is entered by an end user after clicking on a button. I searched in social plugins of Facebook. I found share plugin but it is sharing only links but not the text. How can I post the text to Facebook? In my application, I'm using normal "textarea" to enter the text/status and I'm using a submit button to post it. I want to post the entered text to my timeline in Facebook. Is there any plugin available for this? Please suggest.

Thanks,
Dinakar.

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript SDK

```
<script>
        function share()
        {
            var obj = {
              method: "feed",
              link: "Facebook page hyperlink",
              picture: "Picture hyperlink",
              name: "Title",
              caption: "A short caption right below the title",
              description: "Description"
            };

            function callback(response) {
              document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
            }

            FB.ui(obj, callback);
        }
</script>
```

For More info: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

Comment: I'm giving like this: link as "https://www.facebook.com/mumbaiindians",name as "Post Status",caption as "Share your thoughts",description as myStatus(text entered by user). Whenever I clicked on submit,I'm getting an FBError dialog and it shows "An error occurred. Please try again later." Is this the way to configure it? I have given a page as link and also I tried with my fb username. Both the times I'm getyting the same error. Please suggest.